# How to deal with classes with same purpose from different libraries?

Tags: design-patterns, c++, architectural-patterns, enterprise-architecture

I have a question regarding software design/architecture.

Are there any best practices or design patterns regarding the usage of classes with the same purpose from different libraries?

Let's imagine this simple `project P` which uses two libraries `A` and `B`. `A` and `B` both have a class to deal with 3D-Positions (this question is not about naming problems). `Library A` has the class Position to store x, y, z values. Library B has a similar class:

```
namespace A 
{
    class PositionA { ... }
}

namespace B 
{
    class BPosition { ... }
}
```

In the `project P` both Position classes are used depending on the current use-case and sometimes there is a need to convert one into another.

My goal what i want to achieve now is to abstract this Position classes away. So that the `Project P` should only deal with `IPosition` and the sub-projects which wrap the library should deal with the implementation type, e.g.:

```
namespace AbsractDataLayer{
    class IPosition{};
}

namespace AWrapper {

    class AWrapPosition : public IPosition{
        AWrapPosition(PositionA& pos) : _Pos(pos) {}
        
        PositionA& _Pos;
    };
    
    class Foo{
    public:
        IPosition* Get() { return new AWrapPosition(PositionA()));

        void Do(IPosition* position){
            auto pos = dynamic_cast<AWrapPosition*>(position);
            if(pos){
                ... // correct type
            }
            else {
                ... // what to do here, I need to convert to the correct one?
            }
        }
    };
}

namespace BWrapper {

    class BWrapPosition : public IPosition{
        BWrapPosition(BPosition& pos) : _Pos(pos) {}
        
        BPosition& _Pos;
    }
    
    class Foo{
    public:
        IPosition* Get() { return new BWrapPosition(BPosition()));

        void Do(IPosition* position){
            auto pos = dynamic_cast<BWrapPosition*>(position);
            if(pos){
                ... // correct type
            }
            else {
                ... // what to do here, I need to convert to the correct one?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem which arises is the conversion from one type into another which I cannot think of a clean way to do.

As a goal I wanted to achieve that `AWrapper` wraps `library A` (so that project can only see A-types) and the same applies to `B`. `Project P` should not know about `A` and `B` at all, only know the Abstract-Data-Layer type and the wrappers.

To summarize my questions:

1. Is this a good way to deal with these kind of problems or is there a better way? Keep in mind that this solution is used to use DI for unit testing and the goal that these libraries could be easily exchangable, therefore I want P to be loosely coupled as possible to any dependency
2. And then the bigger question: How could I deal with converting one type into on another if `project P` should not care about that stuff?

This question is asked with C++ context (even the code is some pseudo/c++) This question can also be applied to C# or any other OOP-language if wanted.

Comment: This gets interesting when you have to deal with geometric operations which produce new positions from existing ones. For example, lets say the midpoint M from two existing point P and Q: If P and Q are of type "PositionA", M is probably of the same type. If P and Q are of type "BPosition", M will be, too. But when P and Q are of type `IPosition`, with an arbitrary combination of underlying wrapped types, what underlying type shall M then have?

Comment: ... so this project P makes most sense if P is a generic library and does not contain such operations for producing new points. From your question, however, it is unclear what kind of operations you want to place in P.

Comment: The key issue to consider here is *how* your project P uses the positions (in terms of the interface that P needs) - e.g., does it just pass these objects around, or does it extract the values, does it mostly perform some higher level operations not supported by the existing position interfaces, are there edge-case usage scenarios that make creating a unified design difficult (and can these be taken out of the design and treated as special cases), etc. Things like that. Also, are these two position types the only ones (you don't expect to introduce a third one)?

Comment: One option to consider is not to use an abstraction based on an interface, but one based on data. The feasibility of this depends, again, on what exactly your P needs to do. P could declare its own point type (or just pick one of the existing two, if you don't mind depending on that particular library), and do all of the work P is directly responsible for using that type. When it needs to interact with a lower level component, it passes *that* type to the component, and lets the component convert it back and forth at the boundary (assuming that boundary crossings aren't performance critical).

Comment: @FilipMilovanović only in the example it were 2. In "reality" right now there are 4 and they are handleable. But it could be that the number grows up (and some of them could be exchanged later on)

Comment: @DocBrown that is also a good comment. I thought about defining one type as the "base" type in which all conversions could happen if it could be not determined

Comment: @DocBrown I need to operate on the classes and pass them around to further projects and also to be displayed in UI e.g.

Answer (score 2):

Your wrapper class should probably not just be a "holder" from which you can get the underlying object, but also abstract the functionality you need. For example (excuse syntax errors, I don't write much C++):

```
class IPosition {
public:
  virtual double x() = 0;
  virtual double y() = 0;
  virtual double z() = 0;
}

class AWrapPosition : public IPosition {
public:
  AWrapPosition(PositionA& pos) : _Pos(pos) {}
  
  double x() { return _Pos.GetX(); }
  double y() { return _Pos.GetY(); }
  double z() { return _Pos.GetZ(); }
private:
  PositionA& _Pos;
}
```

and similar code for `BWrapPosition` which abstracts away whatever functionality `Position` exposes for getting the individual components. Now your `Foo.Do()` can just call `IPosition.x()` etc and truly doesn't need to know about whatever the underlying types are.

As a general rule, if you're ever downcasting (`dynamic_cast`) you're probably not doing it right as that means you're breaking the abstraction of whatever object you're using.

Comment: That comment with dynamic_cast I did expect. I also am trying it right now with this solution you mentioned. I also like it because it is easy to write test doubles.

Answer (score 1):

If `PositionA` and `BPosition` have the same *names* for the members you are interested in, you can write all your algorithms as templates. Otherwise you can write similar wrappers, but they don't need to have `virtual` members.

```
namespace A 
{
    struct PositionA { 
        double x; 
        double y; 
        double z;
    }
}

namespace B 
{
    class BPosition { 
    public:
        double get_x(); 
        void set_x(double); 

        double get_y(); 
        void set_y(double); 

        double get_z(); 
        void set_z(double); 
    }
}

class WrapA {
public:
    double x() const { return pos.x; } 
    void x(double val) { pos.x = val; }

    double y() { return pos.y; }
    void y(double val) { pos.y = val; }

    double z() { return pos.z; }
    void z(double val) { pos.z = val; }
private:
    A::PositionA pos;
}

class WrapB {
public:
    double x() const { return pos.get_x(); } 
    void x(double val) { pos.set_x(val); }

    double y() { return pos.get_y(); }
    void y(double val) { pos.set_y(val); }

    double z() { return pos.get_z(); }
    void z(double val) { pos.set_z(val); }
private:
    B::BPosition pos;
}
```

This also means you can create new instances when needed as results or intermediate values.

```
template <typename Position>
Position do_things(Position a, Position b) {
    // stuff, constructing intermediate Position values where neccecary
}
```

With C++20 you can define a `concept` to be more explicit in your requirements.

```
template<typename T>
concept Position = requires (const T & read, T & write, double val) {
    val = read.x();
    write.x(val);
    val = read.y();
    write.y(val);
    val = read.z();
    write.z(val);
}
```

Comment: When dealing with existing libs with an independent development history, it is usually necessary to wrap at least one of the two libs to get the names equal.

Comment: I did not think about using templates. I need to keep this idea in mind for intermediate operations between types if possible, thanks!